# What's the best way to identify a dialog caller?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-bundle, android-number-picker

I've a form fragment with more than 10 fields. Each of them, on click event, shows a number picker dialog. Now, how can I identify which field generated the value choice on dialog? In the fragment I've a single callback, due to an interface implementation:

```
public interface DialogClickListener {
    void onDialogClick(DialogFragment dialog, Bundle args);
}
```

I instantiate the dialog with:

```
private DialogClickListener clickListener;

public static NumberPickerDialogFragment newInstance(final int fiedlId) {
    NumberPickerDialogFragment dialog = new NumberPickerDialogFragment();

    // Here I can pass arguments to dialog with bundle
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("fieldid", fieldId);
    dialog.setArguments(bundle);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Here I can get the arguments
    final int fieldId = getArguments().getInt("fieldid");

    /* Here I can send the id back to fragment callback dialogclick
     * This happen for real inside positive dialog button
    */
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("fieldid", fieldid);
    clicklistener.onDialogClick(NumberPickerDialogFragment.this, bundle);
}
```

Basically I send the field id to the dialog and then send it back to fragment callback: this way I can switch on id inside fragment. I think this solution is a bit too complex and verbose for its aim. Could you suggest an alternative? Many thanks in advance.